# How to best to listen for POST response in react?

Tags: reactjs, post

I have data in a form that I'd like to load to a database and depending on the state either keep them on the page or move them to a different page.

currently I have the following function attached to the form.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const topic = {id, title, desc, text};
    
        console.log(topic);
        
        const isSuccess = commitData(topicsEndPoint, topic)
        console.log(isSuccess)
        if (isSuccess) {
            history.push(endPoint)
        } else {
            setError("An error has occured.")
        }
    }
```

And commitData is ran like this...

```
export const commitData = (endPoint, data) => {
    let isSuccess = false;

    fetch(endPoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(e => {
        if (!e.ok) {
            throw(e)
        }
        isSuccess = true;
        console.log(isSuccess)
        return isSuccess
    })
    .catch(err => {
        isSuccess = false;
        console.log(isSuccess)
        return isSuccess
    })
}
```

I believe I could get it to work if I passed history and the redirect page into `commitData` but that starts to become more cumbersome than the functions already look.

Right now this doesn't work because `handleSubmit` doesn't wait for a response to come back before moving on.

I think using a hook is the way to go but react doesn't like it because I have it inside `handleSubmit` but even when I capitalized it `HandleSubmit` it didn't like it.

I'm looking for what the best practice would be.

(I tried `await` and `then` attached to `commitData` but it didn't like the syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `handleSubmit()` async:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const topic = {id, title, desc, text};
    
        console.log(topic);
        
        const isSuccess = await commitData(topicsEndPoint, topic)
        console.log(isSuccess)
        if (isSuccess) {
            history.push(endPoint)
        } else {
            setError("An error has occured.")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I got this to work but I had to work on the `handleSubmit` a bit more... I needed to 1) place `await` in front of `fetch` and 2) pull `isSuccess` out of `then` and `catch` and return it directly. Why is that?

Comment: That's because if you want to return sth from fetch, you have to return the whole fetch and then return things from within then/catch blocks